# google cloud storage node client - credentials not working as expected

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a project where I need to access some objects in a gcloud bucket

It work fine with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable, but not when I try using the [keyfilename](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#StorageOptions) option of the `Storage` constructor. Here is a minimal example that shows what is going on:

```js
const {Storage, File} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const path = require("path");

// Fake bucket and file names
const bucketname = "my-bucket";
const filename = "test-file.txt";
// Points to a valid key file for a service account with read & write access to the bucket
const keyPath = path.resolve("./key.json");

const storage = new Storage({keyFile: keyPath}); // note that I'm providing a keyFile here
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketname);
const file = new File(bucket, filename);

async function main() {
  console.log("try without GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
  try {
    await file.download({ destination: "./test.txt" });
    console.log("ok");
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }

  console.log("try with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
  try {
    process.env["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = keyPath;
    await file.download({ destination: "./test.txt" });
    console.log("ok");
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
main();
```

I would expect the output for this to be:

```
try without GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
ok
```

but instead I get

```
try without GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to my-bucket/test-file.txt.
try with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
ok
```

What is going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is dumb but it might help somebody:

the Storage constructor options object has both a `KeyFile` and a `keyFilename` option, with the exact same [description](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/53831cf72f6669d13692c5665fef5062dc8f6c1a/src/auth/googleauth.ts#L65). (to be precise, `StorageOptions` inherits those from `GoogleAuthOptions`)

The [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#StorageOptions) only talks about the `keyFilename` option, but my editor was also showing me `KeyFile` as an autocomplete option, and I used it without thinking too much about it.

`keyFilename` is the one you want to use, not `keyFile` (what is this one for ? No idea)

In short:

```js
new Storage({keyFilename: "/path/to/key.json"}); // this works
new Storage({keyFile: "/path/to/key.json"}); // this doesn't
```